# Got a new hard drive - can't verify serial and it says it was manufactured in 2012

Tags: hard-drive, serial-number, warranty

I've bought two **new** `Hitachi A7K3000 2TB Festplatte 3,5 Zoll 7200rpm 6Gbps` according to my invoice and order page on Amazon.

That the drives label says "APR-2012" looked suspicious to me and I've tried to verify the serial numbers on http://www.hgst.com/portal/site/en/support/warranty/. The page doesn't show me even an expatriation date and says it's not warrenty available for that device. The serials in question are:

- YFH4AXEB
- YGH25HLA

Next thing was to call the German HTSG Support (I'm from Germany) and the terrible to understand (obviously no native German speaker) call center agent told me that, according to his system, the serials are valid and have a warrant until **2017** Seriously? Not really what I expected when intentionally buying a drive with a 5 year warranty in 2015.

Before I've read this page http://www.hgst.com/support/warranty-rma/warranty and asked him if the warranty period starts from the day of purchase or or the manufacturing date. He said day of purchase but I somehow doubt that. I plan to use the drives in a RAID 1 in a NAS and want to be sure I've something more or less reliable and warranty when one of the drives fails.

So my actual question is now: Is this really the part I've ordered [here](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B004Q3QMA4?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00) and is it the same as shown [here](http://geizhals.at/hgst-ultrastar-a7k3000-2tb-hua723020ala640-0f12455-a619373.html?hloc=at&hloc=de)?

There are more differences. The page says HUA723020ALA6**40**/0F124**55** while the sticker on the drives says HUA723020ALA6**41**/0F124**70**. Is this just a newer model or a completely different device?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't take the product information on Amazon as being 100% accurate, they even indicate on that page, the information isn't always 100% accurate.  There is no doubt the drivers were manufactured in 2012, the 5-year warranty is from when the drive was manufactured based on the information you have provided.  The part-number and serial are clearly indicated on the label.  I looked up the serial number and received "Please return drive to the point of purchase or system manufacturer." which indicates that drive isn't eligible for the warranty.

Comment: Well, that's my point, it's contradicting to what I was told by their phone support. I don't care less about the money in the case I need to replace the drive if the warranty is invalid but more about the reliability of the drive because it's already three years old.

Comment: The drive sat unused unless you purchased used, and if it was purchase used, and you cared about reliability that's your own fault for buying a used HDD.  We can't answer if what you ordered is described on the amazon store, only point out, the product information isn't always accurate and amazon makes this clear in multiple places.

Comment: It's not used, at least it looks like that, it's still sealed and I haven't ordered a used drive any way, I would never do that.

Comment: The P/N of 0F12470 indicates that the drive is an A7K3000 series drive. Nothing seems amiss here.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Aye;  Was just about to edit that comment.  Looked it up trying to find the description disclaimer.

Comment: The warranty will start from the date Hitachi sold the drive, unless they accept your proof of purchase. Whether they will depends on who you bought the drive from. If it's an authorized retailer, that's fine. If it's a surplus dealer, probably not.

Comment: Here is the full disclaimer about product descriptions "PRODUCT DESCRIPTIONS 
Amazon attempts to be as accurate as possible. However, Amazon does not warrant that product descriptions or other content of any Amazon Service is accurate, complete, reliable, current, or error-free. If a product offered by Amazon itself is not as described, your sole remedy is to return it in unused condition."

Comment: I noticed many of these drives are sold by third-parties not amazon directly at least on the US amazon website.  I will go as far as to say it can only be purchased from a third-party seller and not Amazon directly.  If you want my opinion. Just return the product to amazon and order something else. You are clearly unhappy with the purchase.

Comment: This is interesting, because i have a similar issue now.
https://superuser.com/questions/1193598/cnmemory-with-2tb-hitachi-hua723020ala641-not-really-new