# CnMemory with 2TB Hitachi HUA723020ALA641 not really new?

Tags: smart, reset

I have buyed a **new** external HDD CnMemory.
Now i connected it and checked the state with a short S.M.A.R.T test.
The result is really surprising, because it seems to be new, but there is a list of old SMART tests that show that the HDD has run over 26845 hours.

It seems that the harddrive statistics had been resetted!
Has anyone seen something before?

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Hitachi HUA723020ALA641
Serial Number:    YGGV69PA
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 224cbe958
Firmware Version: MK7OA840
User Capacity:    2.000.398.934.016 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Mar 29 16:57:31 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (20946) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 349) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   100   100   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   230   230   000    Old_age   Always       -       26 (Min/Max 19/26)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 2  Short captive       Completed without error       00%     26845         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26440         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7240         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: What program(s) did you use to run this test? What results do they give on your other hard drives?

Comment: Google for *Hitachi HUA723020ALA641* gave me a link to amazon.com and the very first comment by a buyer was "This hard drive is NOT NEW AT ALL. And not only "not really new", this has been used 15,123 hours in the past (internal drive data)!", so it looks like there may be a possible scam depending on your seller. A key seems to be that the last test is often a short "captive" test.

Comment: I used a standard short smart test (1 minute) under Linux with smartctl. The interesting result are the old tests that has been run before.
Now i opened the case and i found the manufacturing date FEB-2012 on the label of the harddisk. It is 5 years old and that will fit with running over 27000 hours in a server!

Comment: But i can say that the serial number on the label is identical to the smart test. I think this HDD is a retoure and has been refurbished. Now it is selled as B quality cheap as external drive hardware. But maybe there are some people outside that are able to reset the statistical data and sell it as new?